# android xmlpullparser get need element

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

this is xml
[image]

this is xmlpullparser
[image]

it will get all img.
but I want get img of phil is phil_1 and phil_2.
I looking anywhere but can't get answer.
Can anybody help me ?
thank for reading. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have most of what you need. To complete the comparison, all you have to do is:

```
// Get the attribute name that you first need
case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
    String attr = parser.getAttributeName(null, "phil");
    if(!attr.equals("phil"))
        continue; // continue to the next event type

// So when the code hits this case, you know for sure the attribute type is Phil
case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
    // Just do your regular stuff here
```

Comment: I follow you and change code : String attr = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "phil");
                        if(!attr.equals("phil")){
                            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {

                                img = new imgclass();
                            }
                        }; but nothing show. sorry I just newer in java